# react-router-dom pass the Route props (match, location and history) to the child element when rendering using the child elements Not Working

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

[The docs say](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods):

> Route render methods The recommended method of rendering something
>   with a  is to use children elements, as shown above. There are,
>   however, a few other methods you can use to render something with a
>   . These are provided mostly for supporting apps that were built
>   with earlier versions of the router before hooks were introduced.
>      function You should
>   use only one of these props on a given . See their explanations
>   below to understand the differences between them. Route props All
>   three render methods will be passed the same three route props match
>   location history

But if I render with the recommended way as so:

```
<Router>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
</Router>
```

Can actually the Component Home to access the Route props (location, match and history)?

If so, how can these props be passed or arrive to the Home component?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about the react-router hooks:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks

So it is just as simple as importing the **useLocation** hook and use it:

```
let location = useLocation();
```

My apologies!